# gitlab pull npm packages node_modules from artifact without ping to npmjs.org

Tags: npm, gitlab-ci

In the project that we're working is connecting to internet via proxy. The problem is a lot of domains are blocked and admin refused to unblock some of them for security reasons... Since, the project CI/CD was using git-lab. i though i could build a simple git-lab CI/CD which has a containers that pull packages from npmjs.org and saves them inside the container/cache. Then i could get those dependencies from my container. If the solution works then i can present that the devOps team. So they can improve it if they like... So far, all good... Job run successfully, containers are building artifact... Only problem, that i have: is that when i do `npm i` or `npm ci` locally. It pings the container. Then somehow i can see in the console that the npm still requesting the npmjs.org. And makes the install really slow - probably because we're using a virtual machine for the development environment - however the node_modules folder is just 40mb.  I though, it should not do that "connect to npmjs.org" since i published the node_modules ?!  Could you tell if it is possible to download that without connect to npmjs.org ? Also i didn't want to zip the node_modules and just curl that. Because i wanted to take advantage of the cache.

This is the gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
# .gitlab-ci.yml
image: node:16.16.0
stages:
  - install

cache:
  - key: &global_cache_node_mods
      files:
        - package-lock.json
    paths:  
      - package-lock.json
      - node_modules/
    policy: pull 

install:
  stage: install 
  cache:
    - key: ${CI_JOB_NAME}
      paths:
        - .npm/
        - package-lock.json
      when: on_success
      policy: pull-push
    - key:
        files:
          - package-lock.json
      paths:
        - node_modules/
        - package-lock.json
      when: on_success
      policy: pull-push

  before_script:
    - npm config set legacy-peer-deps=alse
  script:
    - npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline --save-dev
    - echo "//${CI_SERVER_HOST}/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/:_authToken=${CI_JOB_TOKEN}">.npmrc
    - npm publish
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules
      - package-lock.json
```